# Using factory method to create typed HTTP client, ASP.NET Core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, dotnet-httpclient

I'm following guides/docs on registering HTTP client within my application. There are couple of services I need to call so I decided to go with "Typed clients".

In order to call another service I need to use OAuth - since this is service-to-service call, when I obtain access token, I cache it + I have setup periodical refresh of token. This means there's another component `IAccessTokenCache` which gives me access token for service.

Thing I'm struggling to figure out is how to register and configure my typed HTTP client providing it also dependency on `IAccessTokenCache`.

I'm using ASP.NET Core 2.1 (crucial detail, read on).

HTTP client wrapper looks like this (from: [HttpClientFactory in ASP.NET Core 2.1 (Part 2)](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/httpclientfactory-named-typed-clients-aspnetcore) ):

```
public class ServiceFooClient
{
    public ServiceFooClient(HttpClient client)
    {
        Client = client;
    }

    public HttpClient Client { get; }
}
```

And this is how I register and configure client:

```
services
    .AddHttpClient<ServiceFooClient>(
        c =>
        {
            c.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.foo.svc");

            // TODO: grab particular access token from cache
            c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "...");
        })
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<ResponseMonitorHandler>()
    .ConfigureHttpMessageHandlerBuilder(
        b =>
        {
            var handler =
                b.AdditionalHandlers.OfType<ResponseMonitorHandler>().FirstOrDefault();

            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler.ServiceName = "Foo Service";
            }
        });
```

... I'm already configuring HTTP client and even adding my custom HTTP handler. You can see exact point where I want to access `IAccessTokenCache`, but I can't.

## Possible solutions I can think of:

### Configure underlying `HttpClient` in `ServiceFooClient` wrapper, like:

```
// ctor
public ServiceFooClient(HttpClient httpClient, IAccessTokenCache tokenCache)
{
    Client = httpClient;
    Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", tokenCache.GetToken("Foo"));
}
```

This could work nicely, except I don't configuration decoupling - suddenly dedicated HTTP client has part of configuration in `Startup` (base URI, additional HTTP handler) and another part in wrapping class (setting authorization header).

### Not using `AddHttpClient` extension method (and others)

I don't really need to call `HttpClientFactoryServiceCollectionExtensions.AddHttpClient<T>(...)` - I could do all that stuff myself. But as lazy developer... I don't even want to finish this sentence. There's quite a lot of registering inside, so this is just big no no for me.

### Upgrade to ASP.NET Core 2.2

Related to previous point - in 2.1, there's no overload of `AddHttpClient` (2.2: `AddHttpClient<TClient>(this IServiceCollection services, Action<IServiceProvider, HttpClient> configureClient)`) which would accept callback with service provider. Upgrading to 2.2 would be probably the best solution, yet I will have to be pretty sure that nothing else gets broken (and I already know that there is/was BC break with getting/setting request tracing ID on HTTP context). This could be potentially risky, so I'm trying first to solve my issue in scope of 2.1.

Compare branch of 2.1 with 2.2: [HttpClientFactoryServiceCollectionExtensions](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpClientFactory/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/DependencyInjection/HttpClientFactoryServiceCollectionExtensions.cs)

### Custom HTTP handler setting request headers

Same way as I now register `ResponseMonitorHandler`, I could register HTTP handler which has access to `IAccessTokenCache` and sets request authorization header.

But again, as in first case, this decouples configuration of HTTP client. Also if I had several different access tokens, I would either need to implement several HTTP handlers or do some logic deciding what token from cache to use based on request properties.

**Finally, question**: is there any other way I didn't consider? Is there easy solution of this in ASP.NET 2.1? (... apart of just copy-pasting method from 2.2 of course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, there's another extension method in 2.1 [`ConfigureHttpClient(IHttpClientBuilder, Action<IServiceProvider,HttpClient>)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.httpclientbuilderextensions.configurehttpclient?view=aspnetcore-2.1) which does exactly what I need!